# CookieManager is abstract, cannot be instantiated. Why?

Tags: android, okhttp, android-cookiemanager

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

throws "CookieManager is abstract, cannot be instantiated"

I'm importing android.webkit.CookieManager and everything seems fine from the documentation side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the cookiemanager manages all the cookies, you can not create intances of it. That would mean one instance got different cookies that another. The cookiemanager is therefor a so called [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern).
Use `CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()`
You can look it up [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html)